# Will this try with resources close my Connection?

Tags: java, jdbc, garbage-collection

Will this `Connection` be closed after the try with resources?

```
public static String readString(String connection, String sql) throws SQLException {
    try (ResultSet rs = DriverManager.getConnection(connection).createStatement(sql).executeQuery()) {
        if (rs.next()) {
            return rs.getString(1);
        }
    }
    return "";
}
```

I'm sure that the `ResultSet` will, not sure about the connection.

Even more intriguing, what if I generate the connection in a different method?:

```
public static String readString(String connection, String sql) throws SQLException {
    try (ResultSet rs = myMethod(connection).createStatement(sql).executeQuery()) {
        if (rs.next()) {
            return rs.getString(1);
        }
    }
    return "";
}

Connection myMethod(String connection){
    return DriverManager.getConnection(connection);
}
```

This puzzles me because I'am having some memory leaking, but I'm not sure if this could be the culprit.

Comment: It will not. Only the `ResultSet`. So not even the `Statement`. You're leaking two objects.

Comment: Ok, and what if I declare the `Connection` within the try ( Connection ... ; ResultSet ...;) I assume the connection will be closed, will the `Statement` leak even if the `Connection` gets closed?

Comment: No. Closing the connection will also close any statement or resultsets. At least the spec says it will.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, the connection and the statement will not be closed in your code (though they might be reclaimed at a later point by the garbage collector). A try-with-resources will only close the objects that are assigned to the variables in the resources-clause. So intermediate objects created inside the clause that are not assigned to a variable will not be closed by the try-with-resources.

The only thing that ensures everything gets closed is to use:

```
try (Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(connection);
     Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();
     ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(sql)) {
    // ...
}
```

And yes, technically, statements will get closed when the connection gets closed. That is not a good reason to skip declaring a resource correctly though.